# SwiftUI: How to call method from nested ViewModel with Combine?

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, swiftui, combine

I use swiftUI in my project and i create a tabview with PageTabViewStyle and every tab has a specific viewModel and also the view of tabview has a viewModel that all tab's viewModel passed to it.

How I can call a method in my parent viewModel when nested viewmodel change from nested viewModel's such as show nextPage?

but app crashes with this error:
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffee94bcfe8)

```
class NestedViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isSelected = false

}

class ParentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var nestedViewModel: NestedViewModel = NestedViewModel()
    
    var anyCancellable: AnyCancellable? = nil
    
    init() {
        anyCancellable = submodel.objectWillChange.sink { [weak self] (_) in
            self?.objectWillChange.send()
            self?.showNextTab()
        }
    } 

    func showNextTab(){}
}
```

Comment: So what's wrong with your current code? It seems it's already doing what you want it to do? You need to clarify what you want to achieve and how your current code doesn't achieve it.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I want to call showNextStep but it doesn't work and app crashe with Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffee94bcfe8)

Comment: @nicksarno thank you for share your idea but I read in some articles it's not good way and I want to use combine

Comment: That piece of code shouldn't even compile, you need `self?.showNextTab()` instead of `showNextTab()` inside the `sink`.

Comment: @nicksarno passing a parent object into a child object is always a bad idea. It creates a strong coupling between the 2 that makes the child object much less reusable (since it cannot be used without its parent object).

Comment: @DávidPásztor so how are you going to access a function within the parent viewModel from the child viewModel then?

Comment: @nicksarno in this particular case, you shouldn't need to. You can react to the property of the child VM changing from the parent VM. Also, you can always inject closures that the child VM can execute (which closure will point to the parent object's function in this case).

Comment: @DávidPásztor thank you, you are right, in my code I have written it such as you said but in stack i should change it

Comment: @DávidPásztor Good insight. Deleting my comment so others don't get misled. Cheers